# Excel: Copy formatted data fast

Tags: excel

This is a excel question:
I have a excel sheet which is heavily formatted, that is, the column widths have been changed and the cells have color formatting. I have filtered this sheet on certain fields. Now, I want to copy this filtered data to another excel sheet with all the formatting.

So for the only way possible seems like to copy the formatting first using paint formatter one by one for each column but that is very tedious. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy what you want, then paste special three times into your target range: values, columns widths, formats.

**Edit:** Changed order, putting widths before formats.  Otherwise wrapped cells will incorrectly change row height.

Answer (score 0):

To copy the cell values and the formatting use the Camera Tool. This is available on the Command Tab of the customise menu. This Camera Tool copies the cells as a graphic and is dynamic.